# selectively use jsoup to extract text and also some useful tags from xml

Tags: xml, jsoup

I'm trying to use jsoup to extract text from xml but also keep some of the tags since they're useful, how to achieve that?

Maybe something like iterating over the document and taking out one component by it's tag, then iterating over that component and extracting furthur based on the nested tags. but I've not been able to solve that.

```
           for( Element item : doc.select("sentence") )
           {
               for( Element component : item)
               {
                   get the tag of sentence and the words of the 
                   sentence as described below
               } 
           }
```

I have an xml document tagged in this way:

```
<sentences>
  <sentence id="1">
    <tokens>
      <token id="1">
        <word>The</word>
        <CharacterOffsetBegin>0</CharacterOffsetBegin>
        <CharacterOffsetEnd>3</CharacterOffsetEnd>
      </token>
      <token id="2">
        <word>newspaper</word>
        <CharacterOffsetBegin>4</CharacterOffsetBegin>
        <CharacterOffsetEnd>13</CharacterOffsetEnd>
      </token>
      <token id="3">
        <word>cartoons</word>
        <CharacterOffsetBegin>14</CharacterOffsetBegin>
        <CharacterOffsetEnd>22</CharacterOffsetEnd>
      </token>
      <token id="4">
        <word>here</word>
        <CharacterOffsetBegin>23</CharacterOffsetBegin>
        <CharacterOffsetEnd>27</CharacterOffsetEnd>
      </token>
      <token id="5">
        <word>often</word>
        <CharacterOffsetBegin>28</CharacterOffsetBegin>
        <CharacterOffsetEnd>33</CharacterOffsetEnd>
      </token>
      <token id="6">
        <word>portray</word>
        <CharacterOffsetBegin>34</CharacterOffsetBegin>
        <CharacterOffsetEnd>41</CharacterOffsetEnd>
      </token>
      <token id="7">
        <word>Per-Kristian</word>
        <CharacterOffsetBegin>42</CharacterOffsetBegin>
        <CharacterOffsetEnd>54</CharacterOffsetEnd>
      </token>
      <token id="8">
        <word>Foss</word>
        <CharacterOffsetBegin>55</CharacterOffsetBegin>
        <CharacterOffsetEnd>59</CharacterOffsetEnd>
      </token>
      <token id="9">
        <word>,</word>
        <CharacterOffsetBegin>59</CharacterOffsetBegin>
        <CharacterOffsetEnd>60</CharacterOffsetEnd>
      </token>
      <token id="10">
        <word>the</word>
        <CharacterOffsetBegin>61</CharacterOffsetBegin>
        <CharacterOffsetEnd>64</CharacterOffsetEnd>
      </token>
      <token id="11">
        <word>finance</word>
        <CharacterOffsetBegin>65</CharacterOffsetBegin>
        <CharacterOffsetEnd>72</CharacterOffsetEnd>
      </token>
      <token id="12">
        <word>minister</word>
        <CharacterOffsetBegin>73</CharacterOffsetBegin>
        <CharacterOffsetEnd>81</CharacterOffsetEnd>
      </token>
      <token id="13">
        <word>of</word>
        <CharacterOffsetBegin>82</CharacterOffsetBegin>
        <CharacterOffsetEnd>84</CharacterOffsetEnd>
      </token>
      <token id="14">
        <word>Norway</word>
        <CharacterOffsetBegin>85</CharacterOffsetBegin>
        <CharacterOffsetEnd>91</CharacterOffsetEnd>
      </token>
      <token id="15">
        <word>,</word>
        <CharacterOffsetBegin>91</CharacterOffsetBegin>
        <CharacterOffsetEnd>92</CharacterOffsetEnd>
      </token>
      <token id="16">
        <word>buoyed</word>
        <CharacterOffsetBegin>93</CharacterOffsetBegin>
        <CharacterOffsetEnd>99</CharacterOffsetEnd>
      </token>
      <token id="17">
        <word>by</word>
        <CharacterOffsetBegin>100</CharacterOffsetBegin>
        <CharacterOffsetEnd>102</CharacterOffsetEnd>
      </token>
      <token id="18">
        <word>a</word>
        <CharacterOffsetBegin>103</CharacterOffsetBegin>
        <CharacterOffsetEnd>104</CharacterOffsetEnd>
      </token>
      <token id="19">
        <word>spouting</word>
        <CharacterOffsetBegin>105</CharacterOffsetBegin>
        <CharacterOffsetEnd>113</CharacterOffsetEnd>
      </token>
      <token id="20">
        <word>geyser</word>
        <CharacterOffsetBegin>114</CharacterOffsetBegin>
        <CharacterOffsetEnd>120</CharacterOffsetEnd>
      </token>
      <token id="21">
        <word>of</word>
        <CharacterOffsetBegin>121</CharacterOffsetBegin>
        <CharacterOffsetEnd>123</CharacterOffsetEnd>
      </token>
      <token id="22">
        <word>oil</word>
        <CharacterOffsetBegin>124</CharacterOffsetBegin>
        <CharacterOffsetEnd>127</CharacterOffsetEnd>
      </token>
      <token id="23">
        <word>.</word>
        <CharacterOffsetBegin>127</CharacterOffsetBegin>
        <CharacterOffsetEnd>128</CharacterOffsetEnd>
      </token>
    </tokens>
  </sentence>
```

The ideal output would be this:

```
<sentence id="1">
    The newspaper cartoons here often portray Per-Kristian Foss, the finance minister of Norway, buoyed by a spouting geyser of oil. 
</sentence>
```

and so on for the rest of the document, which could potentially contain many sentences, or might also contain just one.

So far I tried:

```
String sentence = doc.select("sentence").text();
```

but all I got was this mess:

```
The 0 3 newspaper 4 13 cartoons 14 22 here 23 27 often 28 33 portray 34 41 Per-Kristian 42
```

Answer (score 0):

voilà

```
           for( Element item : doc.select("sentence") )
           {
               System.out.println("<sentence> " + index );

               String word = item.select("word").text();

               System.out.println(word);

              System.out.println("</sentence>" + "\n");

               index++;
           }
```

Comment: You can also use `.html()` and `.outerHtml()`, which will keep the HTML when printing the text.